# Take current year and set it to calendar

Tags: java

I'm trying to make this code dynamically work so that I don't have to manually change and update the code for it to work when the new year comes around.

The way my calendar works is that I need to set a start date and end date which goes from the current January to the next January, this is manual right now.

This is where I set it for the calendar, and I also use these dates to set a RecyclerView

```
widget.state().edit()
              .setMinimumDate(CalendarDay.from(2020, 1, 1))
              .setMaximumDate(CalendarDay.from(2021, 1, 31))
              .commit();
```

```
String firstDate = "2020-01-01 00:00:00";
String endDate = "2021-01-31 00:00:00";

List<Events> listado = SQLite.select().from(Events.class)
        .where(Events_Table.end_date.greaterThanOrEq(firstDate))
        .and(Events_Table.init_date.lessThanOrEq(endDate))
        .orderBy(Events_Table.init_date.asc())
        .queryList();
```

How can I do this dynamically?

Comment: I think: get the current date, extract the current year from that date, build a new date with day = 1, month = 1 and year = current year. It that what you're after?

Comment: @nicomp the days I think can stay hardcoded but the year is what's important, the thing is also when the current date is in Jan of the next year it has to reset the dates so that it becomes the Jan of the current year and the end date year changes as well. like right now is Jan 2021 which is the end date it would have to change the start date to Jan 2021 and the end date to Jan 2022

Comment: What does `RecyclerView` do? What has SQLite to do with it? Can you rephrase the question without all that overhead?

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what type the set methods expects but here is a simple way to get this and next January 1st

```
Year thisYear = Year.now();
LocalDate thisJanuaryFirst = thisYear.atDay(1);
LocalDate nextJanuaryFirst = thisYear.plusYears(1).atDay(31);
```

Of course if you want to make it really simple you could create strings directly

```
String firstDate = String.format("%d-01-01", thisYear.getValue());
String secondDate = String.format("%d-01-31", thisYear.plusYears(1).getValue());
```